# change slashes in path python fails

Tags: python, path

I try to change a windows path to use in python

```
path = "C:\Lokale schijf\datafiles\BRANDS\AUB\voororders\20230113TC- OPAL.xlsx"
path = path.replace("\\", '/')
path
```

gives

```
'C:/Lokale schijf/datafiles/BRANDS/AUB\x0boororders\x8230113TC- OPAL.xlsx'
```

why and how to solve

Comment: Use `os.path` to manipulate paths in an os-agnostic way. Do not handle paths as strings.

Comment: Some chars after the slashes are escape sequences. Use double slashes `"\\"` to escape properly or use raw strings `r"C:\Windows\...`

Comment: This is because \v and \202 are special characters. Do not use strings to denote paths

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure this is due to \2 and such having possible interpretation (such as \n would mean 'skip a line' ).

You can set that path as a raw string :

```
path = r"C:\Lokale schijf\datafiles\BRANDS\AUB\voororders\20230113TC- OPAL.xlsx"
path2 = path.replace( '\\', '/' )
path2
```

But for handling paths , it could be better to used dedicated libraries like *os.path*